# Calculating upper and lower bound

Tags: function, complexity-theory, lower-bound, toupper

Suppose there is a function **f(x)= 19n^2/5n +1-n**
I want to calculate upper and lower bound. But I had this confusion that whether I have to calculate in terms of n^2? Because dominating term is n^2

or If I solve the above equation as **f(x)= 19n/5 +1-n** *(canceling n in 1st term)* 
then what? Then I have to calculate c1 and c2 in terms of n? because that will be the dominating term .

So, Kindly tell me that in which term do I have to calculate c1 and c2 i.e **n** or **n^2**?? Can I cancel n in **19n^2/5n** or not? What will be its asymptotic form? **f(n)∈Θ(n^2)** or **f(n)∈Θ(n)** ?

Comment: This is more of a math than a programming question, so it is more appropriate for the Math SE.

Comment: Seems you have ended at the wrong site. Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/ is better

Comment: I don't think I am in the wrong site. I know 2nd step is mathematically possible but I want to ask that that while calculating c1 and c2, is it asymptotically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have

```
f(n) = 19n^2 / (5n) - n + 1
```

you can, for the purpose of finding asymptotic bounds, indeed cancel out the `n`'s to obtain

```
f(n) = (19/5)n - n + 1 = (14/5)n + 1
```

The easy way to do this is observing that `(14/5)n` is a dominating term here so `+1` can be ignored, and `14/5` is a (positive) constant which can therefore also be ignored.

Therefore, we have that `f(n) ∈ Θ(n)`.

In terms of lower and upper bound coefficients `c1` and `c2`, this can be motivated by the fact that you can find two such coefficients (greater than zero!) such that `c1 * n` is asymptotically smaller than `f(n)`, whereas `c2 * n` is asymptotically larger than `f(n)`. For instance, consider `c1 = 1` and `c2 = 3`.